# memory requirement in x86 & x64 processors

Tags: c++, 64-bit

we have 3 variables defined in C++ program
int a
char b
int c
what would be the memory occupied by these in x86 & x64 processors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 32-bit systems, the data model standard is ILP32 - int, long, ptr and off_t are all 32 bits (4 bytes) in size.

For 64-bit systems, the standard is LP64 (Long-Pointer 64) - int is 32 bits in size. long, ptr, and off_t are all 64 bits (8 bytes) in size. Char is 1 byte in both cases. You may get a detailed discussion on data model [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Comment: I doubt very much that any standard requires a `char` variable to take only one byte; a `char` array should require only one byte per element.

Comment: @dfeuer Sorry I did not get your concern. Size of Char datatype is 8bits in ILP32 and LP64. In LP64, only longs and pointers change size; the other data types stay the same size as in the ILP32 model.

Comment: Neither of those says anything terribly specific about `char`. A `char` variable (as opposed to an array element or a `struct` field) seems most likely to be represented as a full 32-bit word, unless it disappears altogether into some SIMD operation. Variables (either global variables or ones on the stack) can be represented in all *sorts* of ways, because there is no remotely standard way to find out anything about that representation. Speaking of the C stack, read [Cheney on the MTA](http://www.pipeline.com/~hbaker1/CheneyMTA.html) because it's cool.